# Protestants Choice not to accept a literal translation of John 20:23

Tags: protestantism

Both most Protestants and all Catholics believe in Sola Scriptura of the New Testament. Yet certain passages such as John 20:23 cause much consternation among Protestors, resulting in many articles, perhaps tomes, trying to avoid a literal translation.

> If you forgive anyone his sins, they are forgiven; if you do not forgive them, they are not forgiven (NIV)

The question is why not just use the simplest, - the literal translation?

Comment: The translation is not the issue. The different views are a matter of _interpretation_. The main issue is : To which _type_ of succession is this relevant to, today ? To a Papal succession or to a Ministerial succession ? To a hierarchy of tradition or to the calling of individual ministers  (who minister _the word_ ) by Jesus Christ _personally_ from the throne in heaven ?

Comment: Thank you, Nigel. I think you are referring to the breaking away by Luther. Unfortunately, any theology based on Luther's reformation is suspect to external politics of the time. Hee hee just like the Roman church suffered from a poor pope who thought he could sell forgiveness!

Comment: No, I am referring to the entire history of the body of Christ, subsequent to the resurrection and ascension of Jesus Christ himself. and up to the present day. Both of these successions exist ; it is a matter of interpretation which one we follow.

Comment: I have voted to close the question since the OP has not clarified what _they think_ is the 'literal translation'. It is not clear whether the OP means 'translation' or 'interpretation'. And it is not clear whether the OP appreciates the real issue regarding the actual meaning of the words of the Lord Jesus in this verse : to whom do they apply ? All believers ? Just the twelve ? A succession based on the twelve ? Which succession based on the twelve (papal or apostolic) ? If a suitable edit is made, I shall be able to retract my close-vote.

Comment: With all due respect, your vote to close the question is premature and appears to be an attempt to obfruscate the issue and avoid answering the question. The question centers around whether or not Our Lord made the statement. To whom the statement may have been made is secondary. Jesus made the statement. It appears in the vulgate, in the KJV and in Luther's own translation & more current versions. Since the statement was made, then the question of why Protestants don't follow the teaching, regardless of to whom the authority was given. Please rescind the closing and answer the question.

Comment: You will have to be more clear as to why you think that 'Protestants don't follow the teaching'. Your question does not contain that information and, as I said previously, is therefore lacking in clarity and detail. Nobody (that I know of) publicly denies the proper existence of the statement made by Jesus of Nazareth and reported apostolically. The dispute is, as I made clear, the matter of _succession_ as to who has the right to apply this verse to themselves. This, you seem to be avoiding in the question and simply blaming certain persons for (vaguely) not doing something.

Answer (score 2):

Jesus is speaking to his disciples after his resurrection. They are locked away in an upper room in Jerusalem and they are afraid.

Jesus breathed upon them and they received the Holy Spirit then said:

> If you forgive anyone his sins, they are forgiven; if you do not forgive them, they are not forgiven (John 20:23).

God does not forgive people's sins because we do so, nor does God withold forgiveness because we do.  The forgiveness of sins depends upon whether those who hear the gospel accept or reject Christ Jesus.

That is the simple explanation, and it has always been thus.